# Find the solution of the differential equation: $y'' - 2y' + 3y = x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working towards the solution for the differential equation, and would really appreciate support towards clearing up any mistakes on my solution.

$y'' - 2y' + 3y = x^3$

firstly, I'm trying to find the roots when the following equation is equal to 0.

$y'' - 2y' + 3y = 0$

Using the quadratic formula:

$\frac{b \space \pm \space \sqrt{b^2-4(a)(c)}}{2(a)}$

I get the answer:

$1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1 - \sqrt{2}$

Then finally:

$$c_1e^{1+\sqrt{2}}+c_2e^{1-\sqrt{2}}$$

Then trying to find the solution to $x^3$ using the polynomial coeffcient:

$y_1 = Ax^3+bx^2+cx+D$

Then placing this into the formula above and rearranging (though I'm unsure as to whether I should multiply by 2 and 3 respectively for y' and y), we get:

$A(x^3-3x^2+6)+B(x^2-2x+1)+C(x-1)+D = x^3$

For $A = 1$, $B = 3$, $C = 6$, $D = -3$

Although this doesn't get me the right answer. I would appreciate some guidance!

Comment: You cannot use the quadratic formula like that. It's not a quadratic equation $y''$≠$y'^2$.

Comment: @AdityaSharma, but he is using the quadratic formula for the characteristic equation of the linear ODE, not the ODE itself, right?.

Comment: Oh ok, I havent studied that until yet. My bad, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You have an error with the roots of the equation (that pesky minus sign), we have $$m^2−2m+3=0$$

The roots are
$$m_{1,2}=1±i\sqrt{2}$$

This means there are cosine and sine terms in the homogeneous solution and this is likely the cause of your issues as the particular approach you took is correct.

The final solution is

> $$y(x) = \dfrac{1}{27} \left(9 x^3+18 x^2+6 x-8\right)+c_1 e^x \sin (\sqrt{2} x) + c_2 e^x \cos (\sqrt{2} x )$$

Comment: That is helpful! I've managed to get the right solution as a result. Thank you